# How can I get the difference of fields in html and js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to do multiplication of two fields, but I want to take the result minus the third field (I want to get the different in column of credit).

```js
$.fn.fonkTopla = function() {
  var toplam = 1;
  this.each(function() {
    var deger = fonkDeger($(this).val());
    toplam *= deger;
  });
  return toplam;
};


function fonkDeger(veri) {
  return (veri != '') ? parseInt(veri) : 1;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name^="fiyat"]').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#toplam').html($('input[name^="fiyat"]').fonkTopla());
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-9" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="kapsayici">
    <ul>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Unit Price</th>
          <th>Total</th>
          <th>Paid</th>
          <th>Credit</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="" value="ItemCode" class="mytext" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="fiyat[]" class="mytext" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="fiyat[]" class="mytext" /></td>
          <td><span id="toplam"></span> RWF</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="fiyat[]" class="mytext" /></td>
          <td><span id="toplam_difference_here"></span> RWF</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result will be in the following column

```
<td><span id="toplam_difference_here"></span> RWF</td>
```

Comment: Why do multiple form fields have same name?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include example input and the expected output for that input. The code provided had several errors: a closing / in the script tag, a missing closing ul, table nested in ul without li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add data attr 'noaction' and class 'paid; within the third input paid field

```
<!-- add data attr noaction and class paid within paid field-->
<td><input type="text" name="fiyat[]" data-noaction="true"  class="paid mytext" /></td>
```

On based on data attribute, if the input field is paid, do not multiply.

```
$.fn.fonkTopla = function() {
var toplam = 1;
this.each(function() {
   var deger = fonkDeger($(this).val());

   //get the data attr value
   var no_action= $(this).data('noaction');
   var paid_val = $(this).closest('tr').find('.paid').val();

   //On based on data attribute, if the input field is paid, do not multiply,
   if(!no_action){
   toplam *= deger;

   //take the result minus paid field
   total = toplam - paid_val;
   }
});
return total;
};
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/orwg3aLh/1/)

***Based on comments modify the code.***

In form use class instead of id for multiple row

```
 <!-- 
1- use class insteadd of id for multiple row, Make it text field.  
2- Make it text field, to append the total calculated value
3- And also upadte it to readonly, beacause this field is for display the total calculated amount. -->
<td><input type="text" name="fiyat[]" readonly data-noaction="true" class="toplam mytext" /></td>
```

For multiple row, get the closest row (tr) field value for calculating and display

jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name^="fiyat"]').bind('keyup', function() {
        //For multiple row, get the closest row (tr) field value for calculating and display
        var closest = $(this).closest('tr');
        //change .html to .val to add the value in text field.   
        closest.find('.toplam').val(closest.find('input[name^="fiyat"]').fonkTopla());
    });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kmj6nxos/)

Comment: Hi, how can I apply that js to more than one row? I want to have many different items

Comment: Thank you so much Shivendra, you saved my time. Let me ask you the last question, Is it possible to display the value of toplam in text box (input textbox)?

Comment: I think you have need to update the name attr by fiyat['name'][], like - first row- fiyat['Quantity'][], fiyat['unit_price'][], fiyat[1]['Total'],fiyat['Paid'][]
Second row- fiyat['Quantity'][], fiyat['unit_price'][], fiyat['Total'][],fiyat['Paid'][] etc. After submit the form it will be more easy to get the value by name key.

Comment: I tried to take textbox name in PHP but no luck, error message Notice: Undefined index: Quantity in C:\xampp\htdocs\..... I did something like this <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"fiyat['Quantity'][0]\" class=\"mytext\" /></td> to get Quantity value in PHP
$Quantity2=$_POST['Quantity'][0]; How can I take that value in php